# Keep the batch dimension of Conv1D Variable

Tags: tensorflow, keras

`None` in TensorFlow/keras refers to variable dimension. I would like to build a `Conv1D` layer where the dimension of the batch is variable as `(None, 4, 20)`, please. The input to the Conv1D layer has to be 3D, but the previous layer has only a 1D vector of size 100, so I did is to use `TensorFlow.reshape(input, (1, 4, 25))` then I flattened the output of Conv1D back as the input to the next layer after Conv1D should be `(None, 100)`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.layers 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Attention, Flatten, Dense, Dropout, Lambda, Bidirectional, Conv1D, GlobalMaxPooling1D

def initialize_base_network():
    #passing input to layers
    input = Input(shape=(100,), name="base_input")
    x = Flatten(name="flatten_input")(input)
    x = Dropout(0.2, name="first_dropout")(x)
    x = Attention(use_scale=True)([x,x])
    x = tf.reshape(x, [1, 4, 25])
    x = Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Flatten(name="flatten_input2", input_shape=(None,32))(x)
    x = Dense(128, activation='relu', name="first_base_dense")(x)
    x = Dense(128, activation='relu', name="second_base_dense")(x)
    x = Dropout(0.1, name="second_dropout")(x)
    x = Dense(128, activation='relu', name="third_base_dense")(x)
    
    #return the model
    return Model(inputs=input, outputs=x)

base_network = initialize_base_network()
#plot_model(base_network, show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True, to_file='base-model.png')
base_network.summary()
```

Output:

[image]

But I would like the output to be as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace,

```
tf.reshape(x, [1, 4, 25]) with keras.layers.Reshape([4, 25])(x)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please add a little to what the code you provided does and why mine does not work?